# Каким образом лучше создавать сайт и размещать его в интернете?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Сразу же извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, просто это как раз тот случай когда знания есть, а как применить их не понятно. Буду благодарен за советы / ссылки на определенную литературу. Задача: необходимо создать сайт с форумом. На чем собрался писать \ что сам знаю: HTML\HTML5 + CSS, PHP, Javascript. Так же работал с платформой ASP.NET. Как сделать сайт, чтобы он работал на компьютере \ в компиляторе - я знаю, но как разместить его не очень осведомлен. 
Пытался юзать WordPress с phpmyadmin, но это, как я понял, уже не актуально. 
Вообщем, вопрос в следующем - каким образом можно разместить созданный сайт (html\php файлы, картинки к ним и БД).

P.S: желательно не предлагать сайты по типу ucoz.ru, хочется создать что-то свое фактически с нуля.

Comment: Как размесить: 1) Купить хостинг, 2) Купить домен 3) Залить все файлы через ФТП. Как создать: Создаём базу на хостинге, создаём скрипты цепляемся к базе и так далее, вот к примеру статья https://uguide.ru/kak-sozdat-svoj-forum vB один из актуальных движков=)

Comment: Как можно знать все эти технологии, но не знать что такое хостинг?

Comment: Sergey Archipov, а обязательно так отвечать? Я знаю что такое хостинг, но мне бы хотелось узнать какие хостинги рекомендовали бы нормальные люди (нет, не ты, юный школьник). Поэтому иди и учи уроки.

Comment: Walfter, какие хостинги вы бы посоветовали от себя?)

Comment: @Andrey Dubchak, это был сарказм, и я не юный школьник, вопрос просто был странный

Comment: Хостинг не должен иметь никакого значения. Всегда должна быть возможность в любой момент взять и переехать на любой другой хостинг максимум за час (если речь о небольшом/среднем сайте)

Comment: FirstVds или Fastfox отличные хостинги

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если особо в подробности не вдаваться, то в общих чертах необходимо следующее:

1. Сервр/хостинг. По сути машина где лежат ваши файлы и скрипты, и к которой можно обратиться по сети.
2. На этом самом сервере/хостинге должно быть установлено необходимое ПО для того чтобы, во первых, отвечать на зпросы (сервер, например Apache или Nginx) и для того чтобы интерпретировать ваши скрипты (PHP, NodeJS и прочее). А так же софт для работы с данными (базой данных). Этот софт тоже по сути представляет из себя сервер (MySQL сервер) и ваши скрипты во время работы будут обращаться к нему (точнее это будет делать интерпретатор скриптов)
3. Домен. Это, если коротко, просто запись в базе данных сервера доменных имен. В сети, если не ошибаюсь, есть несколько крупных DNS серверов, с базой, которая из себя представляет просто набор пар [домен => IP]. Получается что ваш браузер, когда вы вводите название домена, в начале запрашивает соответствующий IP у DNS сервера, а затем, получив его, уже делает запрос по этому IP, ПРИ ЭТОМ передавая в этом же запросе и данные о домене.

Хостинг со всем необходимым для работы ваших скриптов можно купить. Домен тоже. Домен как правило стоит не дорого, хостинг дороже. Есть конечно и бесплатные хостинги, например [этот](https://www.000webhost.com/), но по настоящему развернуться вам на них не дадут очень ограниченные ресурсы. Пока не приобретете какой-то платный тариф, все будет тупить и тормозить. Но для тестирования конечно сгодится.

Вы так же можете устроить сервер прямо у себя на компьютере, при этом особо не заморачиваясь с конфигурацией необходимого ПО. Есть готовый инструмент - [OpenServer](https://ospanel.io/), где все необходимое уже собрано воедино и настроено. Он в основном используется для запуска и тестирования локально, но ничего не мешает сделать его доступным извне. В вашем роутере для 80 порта делаете пере-направление на нужный внутренний IP (той машины, где у вас запущен сервер). Немного подправляете конфиги Apache (чтобы дефолтная директория, в которой сервер начинает запускать скрипты, когда вы вводите 127.0.0.1 в браузере, была именно той что вам нужна) и вуаля - ваш сайт теперь доступен по вашему внешнему IP (пока работает ваш компьютер и необходимое ПО, разумеется).

Comment: А касательно форума, что можете сказать? Можно использовать CMS,  к примеру?

Comment: @AndreyDubchak, если не хотите писать свой - можно использовать готовые форумные движки. Форум, по своей своей сути, от какого либо другого веб-сайта ничем не отличается. Скрипты, работа с бд, все как обычно..

Comment: А какую СMS посоветовали бы?

Comment: @AndreyDubchak, ну например можно взять эту - https://www.phpbb.com/. Но лучше просто загуглить "форумные движки", посмотреть их преимущества/недостатки.. Я готовые CMS по работе использую крайне редко, так что мало что могу посоветовать